# How to Add(SUM) the values at certain locations where there is data overlaps, python

Tags: python, numpy

data is of shape [100,100,30]

I need to create the large data by duplicating this (data)array and plot. For example :

```
n= np.zeros([300,300,30])

n[0:100, 0:100, 0:30] = data

n[60:160, 0:100, 0:30] = data

n[0:100, 60:160, 0:30] = data
```

If you observe, there is overlap in the first axis, I wanted to sum the values which overlap at certain positions and replace it at that overlapping position with this sum value

How to do it using numpy, python?

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to create the large data"?

Comment: creating Large array of size (300,300,30)  with the single 3D array of size(100,100,30) by making the duplication of it but need to be overlapped at the certain axis like if you observe first axis.   if you can see that creating big array by the above lines.

Comment: Sounds like `n[60:160, 0:100, 0:30] += data` and `n[0:100, 60:160, 0:30] += data` would do the trick...

Comment: @swenzel  Thanks. It worked out.

Comment: Is there any other way of placing the data in randomly such that data is placed randomly in the array?

Comment: @swenzel  Is there any way to find the average of the values at overlapping locations.... means replace those overlapping loci with the mean values??

Comment: @rajubhai yes. Create a second ndarray `N = np.zeros_like(n)` which keeps track of how many times something was added to each cell (add `1` to `N` like you add `data` to `n`). In the end, deterimine locations of nonzero values `msk = np.nonzero(N)` and do `n[msk] /= N[msk]` and you'll get the average.

Comment: @swenzel  Great. It works...